# how do i handle this string to open my app

Tags: android, redirect, android-intent

i get this string in a browser redirect

intent://view?id=123#Intent;package=com.myapp;scheme=myapp;launchFlags=268435456;end;

how do i work with it ?

found in : http://fokkezb.nl/2013/09/20/url-schemes-for-ios-and-android-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your answer in the part 1 of the same article :

http://fokkezb.nl/2013/08/26/url-schemes-for-ios-and-android-1/

Your activity must have an intent filter matching the given intent
Here you have :

```
package=com.myapp;scheme=myapp
```

Your app package must be *com.myapp* and the url scheme is *myapp://*
So you must declare your activity like that :

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
         <data android:scheme="myapp" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Then your activity will be automatically opened by android.

Optionnaly you can work with the uri received from your code, for example in the onResume method (why onResume ? -> because it is always called after onNewIntent) :

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.getData() != null) {
            Uri uri = intent.getData();
            // do whatever you want with the uri given
        }
    }
```

If your activity uses onNewIntent, i recommend to use setIntent so that code above is always executed on last intent :

```
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
    }
```

Does this answers your question ?

Comment: What happens is this:

I click a link in a email which sends me to the browser, the browser wants to redirect me back to this url : intent:// as pasted above

Comment: your answer is correct, except for one small error - > the content you wrote in "onResume" MUST! be read in onNewIntent, otherwise it is a different intent, and all the data from the url is wiped out. after you fix this in your answer, i will accept it as correct