# application is not intercepting url

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to intercept my own app's URL on android so that the user can open the URL in the app rather than on the browser. (I don't have browser support yet).

This is what I'm doing

```
<activity android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK_ACTIVITY" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:host="myapp.com" />
        <data android:pathPattern=".*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For some reason anytime I open `myapp.com` it still keeps opening in the browser, without giving me the option to open the URL in my app. I am trying this on my emulator with API 16 running on it. I've closed the emulator several times and started it again but still its the same behavior.

To avoid any errors in the URL of my personal app. I even experimented with:

```
         <data android:host="goo.gl" android:scheme="http" />
         <data android:host="goo.gl" android:scheme="https" />
```

The app DOES intercept the above url but ONLY the first time. If I click 'JUST ONCE' in the options presented, I don't get the option ever again until I restart the emulator.

Has anyone gone through this? What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Delete `android:pathPattern`, since you don't seem to be using it, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer helped me : [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545373/how-do-i-handle-this-string-to-open-my-app)

if you add the package name to the intent, it will open your app by default

Comment: Following the link on that URL (http://fokkezb.nl/2013/09/20/url-schemes-for-ios-and-android-2/) I followed the advice for HTTP Scheme (bottom of the page). I don't see what is different in that snippet and what I'm doing.

Comment: I've abandoned the HTTP scheme and I'm now creating my own scheme. This is forwarded by the JS in my website. However, how do I get the URL in my app after my app opens up? I've asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447985/how-to-receive-a-url-from-my-android-app-after-being-forwarded-from-browser

Comment: when you click on a link in the js website your link should be intent://your.scheme/someotherstuff;package=your.package  and that will make the phone open your app if its installed, or go to the google play if its not