# How to receive a URL from my android app after being forwarded from browser.

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

When a user visits the browser page for my app I am forwarding them to a url scheme like so:

```
intent://share?id=123#Intent;package=com.aerstone.mobile;scheme=myapp;launchFlags=268435456;end;
```

I've tested this and this works fine. Now, when the user visits my app's home page from the browser and have the app installed, the app automatically opens up.

Relevant part from my manifest is:

```
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ui.activity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <!-- add the above launchMode attribute -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- add the below additional intent-filter -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Question**

After the app opens up, how can I fetch the URL? I want to fetch the `id=123` part of the URL. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `getIntent().getData()` in `onCreate()`, or `getData()` on the passed-in `Intent` to `onNewIntent()`, depending on whether your activity was already created or not. That will return the `Uri` representing your URL.

Comment: I added a debug message in all three: `onResume()`, `onCreate()`, and `onNewIntent`. The result was that debug message in `onNewIntent` came first followed by `onResume`. Message in `onCreate` never showed. Can you explain what this means?

Comment: @birdy: It means that your activity already existed. `onCreate()` is called when an activity is *created*. If an instance of your activity is already running, and the configuration is such that the new request is supposed to go to that instance (presumably helped here by `android:launchMode="singleTask"`), then `onNewIntent()` is called *instead* of `onCreate()`.

Comment: Awesome!! that explains things much better. BTW I enjoyed your book even though I have not finished the entire thing. Also, instead of using a unique url scheme I just wanted to intercept my apps url and open it in my app (seemed much easier) to do. However, I was never able to achieve it and so had to abandon that option. Unique url scheme seems to be working consistently. I had asked a question regarding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23445102/application-is-not-intercepting-url

Answer (score 1):

In onCreate()

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData(); //Returns the URI that was used. 
String id = uri.getQueryParameter("id"); //Gives any parameter passed in the URI.
```