# start application from browser work in some devices only

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, openurl

i"m trying to launch my application when user enter url in the browser

**this code works perfect on some devices like HTC and doesn't work on others like Galaxy s2 and s3 ... what is the difference and how do i solve it ?**

lest say if he is type my://value=2  than my application will start .

i"m trying the following code :

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.blah.blah.BootActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="false"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
         <data android:scheme="my" />
         <data android:host="e.com"
                android:scheme="http" />    
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and i have the permissions :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

update :

i took the code from : https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/webmasters/app

```
<activity android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
           android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
     <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://example.com/gizmos" -->
         <data android:scheme="http"
               android:host="example.com"
               android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

and same issue here , working on HTC and doesn't on galaxy's

Comment: Hezi, what does the URL that you are trying to open look like ?

Comment: my://value=2 for example

Comment: Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20546099/2136812

Comment: my package is : com.xxx.my so it is already set as they suggested

Comment: the package should appear in the url that you are sending to
something like my://value=2&package="com.yourpackage.namespace";

Comment: interesting idea but it didn't work

Comment: post the web code that's supposed to work

Comment: there isn't one . it simply works when this scheme called , as i wrote only in some devices